# Will Hazrat Isa A.S come with his miraculous powers again?

Tags: sunni, prophets, prophet-isa, day-of-judgement

This question has been bothering me since a year. I have a lot of knowledge about Islam but what I doubt is about that Will Hazrat Isa (A.S) come back with all his power like Resurrecting someone by the permission of Allah or making a blind see etc. I know that He will have the power to kill the disbelievers and dajjal with his breath or with his vision as far as He can see. Answer with reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Hazrat Isa will come with Imam Zaman (Mahdi) while the reappearance... based on Shiite view. does ur nice question asking for Sunni view? if so, I suggest you to add it (Sunni view) in ur question to be more clear that you are looking for the view of Sunni. (I said that, cos I saw in ur tags the word "Sunni".  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Salam Mohammad,

There's a whole field of study that speculates about the end of the world. Muslim tradition does say that Jesus A.S will return, but I would argue that he does not have "God-like" power. He was a man, albeit a great one who changed the course of history, and his miracles were granted by God.

As a suggestion, and to get peace of mind, I wouldn't worry about the literalness of this, nor would I wait around for Jesus to return. As Muslims we believe that the world will be destroyed eventually, that it cannot continue forever, and of course that it is in God's hands. Whether Jesus returns in flesh is just for speculation. It's worth it to read the tafsir of such verses that say this and reflect on what it mean. Jesus has been followed by many but misrepresented as a god. His return could mean that the world ends with understanding the true power of the One God.

Just an opinion, I am definitely not a scholar. But I hope that helps!

Comment: FYI, I think there are Hadith which describe the possible appearance of him like 'a red colored *human* man'. But, yes, him having the same <strike>power<strike> *permissions* again as he had before, is I too don't know, **God knows the best.**

Comment: +1 for your saying that he doesn't have God-like powers.